# For loop in android create gaps between the items

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, for-loop

I am passing the json in the navigation slider where its getting gap 2 spaces gap between the items. I am not able understand why its happening like that. I had tried several method but I am not successful.

**Navigation.Java**

```
private void navmenu() {
        String menuurl = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/categories.php";
        Log.i("menuurl", menuurl);
        JsonObjectRequest menuobj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, menuurl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menu1=response.getJSONArray("menu1");
                    for (int i=0;i<menu1.length();i++){
                        JSONObject first=menu1.getJSONObject(i);
                        Data navgadata = new Data();
                        navgadata.setCatergory(first.getString("category"));
                        datalts.add(navgadata);
                        JSONArray item=first.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int j=0;j<item.length();j++){
                            Data secdata=new Data();
                            JSONObject second=item.getJSONObject(j);
                            secdata.setId(second.getString("id"));
                            secdata.setSubcatergory(second.getString("title"));
                            datalts.add(secdata);
                        }


                    }

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listnadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("res", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(menuobj);
    }
```

This is my XML file **navigation.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/categories" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/subcategories" />
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Navgation_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Data> catdata;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public Navgation_adapter(Context context, List<Data> catdata){
    this.context=context;
    this.catdata=catdata;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return catdata.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return catdata.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(view==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_list,viewGroup,false);
        holder.categories= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categories);
        holder.subcategories= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subcategories);
        view.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Data ndata=catdata.get(i);
    holder.categories.setText(ndata.getCatergory());
    holder.subcategories.setText(ndata.getSubcatergory());

    return view;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView categories,subcategories;
}
```

Here the image how I am getting view

[image]

Comment: What Adapter are you using? If it's custom, please post it. Actually, it looks like your setting one of the TextViews in your list item layout to `INVISIBLE` depending on whether it's a category or subcategory. If that's the case, you should be using `GONE` instead. But if that's not the problem, please post the Adapter.

Comment: i had updated the post please check it

Comment: i am not using any visible or invisible

Comment: Where are you using Navgation_adapter ? Plz  upload xml of it.

Comment: navigation.xml updated it

Comment: how can i set empty textview GONE?

Comment: `if(ndata.getCatergory() == null) { holder.categories.setVisibility(View.GONE); holder.subcategories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ...}`. Then, in the `else`, do the opposite.

Comment: @Ayubbaba issue is in the way you are using collections for displaying data for each list item subcategory is there but main category text may come empty so thts why its displaying empty text not empty extra space

Comment: @Ayubbaba what i can suggest for this type of category & subcategory related list display ... use Expandable Listview rather thn handling conditions for empty check ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Mike M its worked can u explain me please

Comment: user1140237 i dont want to use the expandable Listview

Comment: for debugging, you may want to set different background color for id.categories and id.subcategories ... then you will be able to see which one is contributing to the extra spaces.

Comment: yes thank u but y its taking extra empty data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same `Data` class for both categories and subcategories. When the JSON data is a category, you set the category `String` on the `Data` object, but not the subcategory `String`. It's vice versa when the data is a subcategory. The `String`s you don't set remain null, and setting null text on a `TextView` leaves it blank. So, when a list item represents a category, the top `TextView` displays the category name, but the bottom `TextView` is blank. The next item will be a subcategory, and for the same reasons, the top `TextView` will be blank. The two adjacent blank `TextView`s leave a large gap between the category and its first subcategory. The blank category `TextView`s in the following subcategory items leave smaller gaps between those items.

If you want to stick with as much of your current setup as possible, one solution is to toggle the `TextView`s' visibility properties depending on the type of data, which we can determine by checking for a null `Data` object member.

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ...     
    Data ndata = catdata.get(i);

    holder.subcategories.setText(ndata.getSubcatergory());
    holder.categories.setText(ndata.getCatergory());

    if(ndata.getCatergory() == null) {
        holder.categories.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.subcategories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
    }
    else {
        holder.categories.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.subcategories.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
    }

    return view;
}
```